# Is it possible to run polymer locally?

Tags: polymer

Might be a very stupid question, but right now I'm running a project using Polymer-Project elements on a remote server.
I'm going to be away from network for a while, but I still want to work on this project offline. However, I can't get it running locally on a windows machine, even though all the dependencies are CSS/HTML/JS. Is there something I'm missing? All the paths are relative, and I double-checked them just in case.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the error or unexpected output you are seeing. Otherwise, all we can do is guess at things you might have already tried.

Comment: Question is very simple: Is it possible to run a Polymer-based project locally? yes/no

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

You only need to have a web server running on your computer, as Polymer pages must be served from a web server.

Apache, ISS, Nginx or other HTTP servers will work; If you have no server in your computer, you need to follow the instructions in https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html to start a quick Pyhton HTTP server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You just need a local web server.

**For Mac/Linux,**
Python comes generally pre-installed. Hence, you can directly start a web server from any directory using,

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

If python is not available, then you can install [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) for Mac and [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for Linux system to start a local web server.

**For Windows,**
You've got [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) that does the same thing for windows.

---

For a lightweight static web server, you could use [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) that runs on all three platforms mentioned above.